AVD loading infinitly in Andriod Studio and not seen in VSCode
I started my journey with flutter. I did as the tutorials said, but I cannot run app on AVD. When I run AVD it shows "Connecting to the Emluator" infinitly spinning.

I've tried different things: wiping the data of emulator, creating new AVD, even uninstalling HAXM for intel (which did not work). I don't know what to do as no solutions I've found were helpful.
Also when i run the emulator from vscode palette it shows up, but its black and when I try to run my main.dart (even with the flutter run command) the flutter wasn't seeing it.
Android studio version: 2023.3.1 Patch 1
AVD: Pixel 7 with API 34-ext8
Windows: 11
Flutter SDK version: 3.22.1
Dart: 3.4.1
I'd be really helpful if someone could help me resolve it.

Very much a shot in the dark, but make sure the emulator version is up-to-date.

It wasn't, as well as Android Build Tools, but it hasn't changed anything. Nevertheless, thanks for helping
